# How to free up memory in Pyspark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Here is sample of my code:

```
ses = SparkSession.Builder().config(conf=conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
res = ses.sql("select * from tbl")
res.write.format("hive").saveAsTable("tablename"), mode='append')
res.unpersist()
```

But after execution `htop` shows, that this process uses 63GB of RAM. Also I tried `ses.catalog.clearCache()`, nothing, still 63GB used.

How can I free up memory without reinitialising spark session?

Edit.
Also I tried to delete `res` object, still 63gb in htop.
Also tried this, it prints nothing:

```
for (id, rdd) in ses.sparkContext._jsc.getPersistentRDDs().items():
    print(id, rdd)
```

Comment: deleting ram is done by deleting variables with `del` statement as far as I know

Comment: I tried to delete `res`, this also doesn't help

Comment: After deleting, you can force the garbage collector to release unreferenced memory with `gc.collect()`. `import gc; gc.collect()`.

Comment: tried gc, nothing :(

Comment: Try first `spark.catalog.clearCache()`  and then `res.checkpoint()`. The first one will mark the cache for cleaning when the second one will remove the lineage.

Comment: @Slavka I have faced same issue. can you please guide me how to reduce memory that spark session occupied?